# Will html auto redirect code work when using webview?

Tags: android, html, redirect, android-webview

I'm fairly new to coding and is just starting to get into Android Studio. I have an app made from web language that I'm importing into Android Studio through webview. I'm having trouble getting the auto redirect and Onclick functions to work. Is it even possible if so how if not what would be a good alternative?

Answer (score 0):

### Best Way

```
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true); 

       String html = response.body().string();
       Document document = Jsoup.parse(html);
       Elements elements = document.select("video");
       Log.d("elments", "" + elements);
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", String.valueOf(elements), 
        "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
```

### use below library in gradle

```
  implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.10.2'
```

Comment: Would this go into the MainActivity? How do I add the library you suggested into the gradle?